# php a link parameter

Tags: php

I have doubt on how to get two values in a link and pass that to the edit function. Help pls.......

Following is the code,

I want both manufacturedate and product code to be passed to the get[edi],

```
<td > <a name="edit" href="productwarrantymaster.php?edi[]=<? echo $record['ProductCode']; echo $record['ManufactureDate'];?>">Edit</a></td>
```

Following is the code for edit function,

```
if(!empty($_GET['edi']))
{
$prmaster =$_GET['edi'];
$Manufactu =$_GET['edi'];


$result=mysql_query("SELECT * FROM productwarranty where ProductCode ='".$prmaster."' and ManufactureDate ='".$Manufactu."'");
$myrow1 = mysql_num_rows($result);//mysql_fetch_array($retval);

        if($myrow1==0)  
        {
            ?>
            <script type="text/javascript">
            alert("No Data Found!!");
            </script>
            <?
        }
        else
        {
           $myrow = mysql_fetch_array($result);

           $ProductCode = $myrow['ProductCode'];
           $WarrantyPeriod = $myrow['WarrantyPeriod'];
           $ProRataPeriod = $myrow['ProRataPeriod'];
           $ManufactureDate = $myrow['ManufactureDate'];
           $ApplicableFormDate = $myrow['ApplicableFormDate'];
        }
        $prmaster = NULL;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this code

```
<a name="edit" href="productwarrantymaster.php?ProductCode=<?=$record['ProductCode']?>&ManufactureDate=<?=$record['ManufactureDate'];?>">Edit</a>
```

and change here like,

```
if(!empty($_GET['ProductCode']))
{
  $prmaster  = $_GET['ProductCode'];
  $Manufactu = $_GET['ManufactureDate'];
```

Comment: how can i pass this to edi function?

Comment: You should encode your parameters with `urlencode()` (http://php.net/manual/en/function.urlencode.php) and `urldecode`.

Comment: @sairam manigandan -Glad to help you. Then accept this as a answer.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
<td><a name="edit" href="productwarrantymaster.php?edi=1&prodCode=<?php echo $record['ProductCode'];?>&manuDate=<?php echo $record['ManufactureDate'];?>">Edit</a></td>
```

THIS NEEDS VALIDATION!!!!!!!!

```
if(!empty($_GET['edi']))
{
  $prmaster =$_GET['prodCode'];
  $Manufactu =$_GET['manuDate'];


$result=mysql_query("SELECT * FROM productwarranty where ProductCode ='".$prmaster."' and ManufactureDate ='".$Manufactu."'");
$myrow1 = mysql_num_rows($result);//mysql_fetch_array($retval);

        if($myrow1==0)  
        {
            ?>
            <script type="text/javascript">
            alert("No Data Found!!");
            </script>
            <?
        }
        else
        {
           $myrow = mysql_fetch_array($result);

           $ProductCode = $myrow['ProductCode'];
           $WarrantyPeriod = $myrow['WarrantyPeriod'];
           $ProRataPeriod = $myrow['ProRataPeriod'];
           $ManufactureDate = $myrow['ManufactureDate'];
           $ApplicableFormDate = $myrow['ApplicableFormDate'];
        }
        $prmaster = NULL;
}
```